# Why string value is not being updated in my C code?

Tags: c

I cannot understand what is the problem with my code. I allocated space for a string and I passed it by reference to unparse_symbol function. Though,somehow str is not being set to the strings I am proving in switch statements, e.g. str = "ADD" does not set str to "ADD". I cannot really understand what is the issue.. space is allocated and pointer is passed.

Thanks for help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {ADD, MULT, MINUS, DIV, MOD, BAD} op_type;

    void unparse_symbol(op_type op, char *str)
    {
      switch (op) {
      case ADD:
        str = "ADD";
        break;
      case MULT:
        str = "MULT";
        break;
      case MINUS:
        str = "MINUS";
        break;
      case DIV:
        str = "DIV";
        break;
      case MOD:
        str = "MOD";
        break;
      case BAD:
        str = "BAD";
        break;

      default: str = "DEFAULT_CASE";
      }
      return;
    }

int main(void){

    char *string = calloc(10, 1);
    op_type add = ADD;
    unparse_symbol(add, string);
    printf("%s \n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str = "XXX";` --> `strcpy(str, "XXX");` Also `"DEFAULT_CASE"` too long.

Comment: the way you did is just modifying the local variable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i would suggest to use `strncpy`.

Comment: "I passed it by reference" - no you didn't. That's not even a thing in C.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: And what would suggest for the length parameter?

Comment: @FredLarson depends on how many OP allocates. obviously `strcpy` gives a counterexample here when fall to the default case. it's not safe.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Right, but the allocation size isn't known in this function, as it's not passed in. `strncpy` isn't entirely safe either; it has a nasty feature of failing to null terminate when the source string is longer than the given length. That can also lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @FredLarson it's safe, as long as user remembers to put a '\0' manually at the last byte. in this case, OP has hard coded the length of allocation, he could absolutely make the length param equal to it, using macro. `strncpy` is not totally safe should not make using `strcpy` comfortable. if OP in any sense wants to copy the string, `strdup` serves better.

Comment: this line: default: str = "DEFAULT_CASE"; has a few problems.  1) as mentioned elsewhere, this does nothing to the str var in main() 2) even if it did work correctly, the text is longer than the allocated memory in Main() which can/will result in a seg fault event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `unparse_symbol` parameter `str` is a local varaiable of the function. After exiting the function this local variable will not be alive. Changes of this local variable within the function does not influence on the original object that was passed as the argument.

You should declare the function like

```
void unparse_symbol(op_type op, char **str)
```

and within the function use an assignment like

```
  switch (op) {
  case ADD:
    *str = "ADD";
    break;
```

Also there is a memory leak in the program. To escape it you could define the function the following way

```
void unparse_symbol(op_type op, char *str)
{
  switch (op) {
  case ADD:
    strcpy( str, "ADD" );
    break;
```

So either remove the memory allocation and define the function as

```
void unparse_symbol(op_type op, char **str)
```

using assignments to the pointer in the switch statement

or keep the same function declaration but use function `strcpy` to copy string literals in the allocated memory pointed to by the pointer.

In the last case you need to free the allocated memory using function `free`

```
free( str );
```

Also take into account that if you will use the last case then you have to change statement

char *string = calloc(10, 1);

increasing the size of allocated memory because the string literal used under label `default` has more than 10 characters.

```
default: str = "DEFAULT_CASE";
```

Comment: @FemX See my last note in my post.

Answer (score 2):

You point the local pointer `str` in the function to a string literal

```
str = "ADD";
```

This will nor copy the string or update the string which was passed to the function.

You have to copy the string to the array pointed to by `str`

```
strcpy( str , "ADD" ) ;
```

Since you allocated ten characters for `str`

```
char *string = calloc(10, 1);
```

You shouldn't copy more than nine characters + the null terminating character.

Answer (score 1):

That's because "whatever" is char* type, so you change the pointer inside the function, but not the string itself. Recommendation will depend on what you are actually trying to do: rewrite the string itself? or change the pointer outside the function to a string that exists only inside the function? The latter is, of course, not going to work...

Answer (score 0):

Vlad's answer is the best so far.

Keep in mind there's a better way to transform an enum value (any value, actually) to a string.

You can take advantage of the C preprocessor.

```
#define STRINGIFY(VAL) "" # VAL

const char* addStr = STRINGIFY(ADD);
```

It concatenates VAL to an empty string, thus creating a string that contains VAL.

Comment: you can't transform an enum in a variable to string if you use macro.

Comment: I wasn't talking about an **enum value in a variable**, but just an enum value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
void unparse_symbol(op_type op, char **str)
{
  switch (op) {
  case ADD:
    *str = "ADD";
    break;
  case MULT:
    *str = "MULT";
    break;
  case MINUS:
    *str = "MINUS";
    break;
  case DIV:
    *str = "DIV";
    break;
  case MOD:
    *str = "MOD";
    break;
  case BAD:
    *str = "BAD";
    break;

  default: *str = "DEFAULT_CASE";
  }
  return;
}

int main(void){

char *string = calloc(10, 1);
op_type add = ADD;
unparse_symbol(add, &string);
printf("%s \n", string);

return 0;
}
```

I hope you got your answer. You should find out why this is working.

Comment: `char *string = calloc(10, 1);` --> `char *string;` and `str = "MOD";` typo

Comment: @BLUEPIXY passing the address of string will work ..?

Comment: Your answer has become so. it will work. However, note that it can not change.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what you meant by can't change. `add=DIV` will work fine ?

Comment: `char *` means can be changed. but String literal is not allow change. (The behavior is undefined if it change)

Comment: `char *string = calloc(10, 1);` make a memory area that are not referenced.(it's memory leak)

Comment: It can not be `free` in order to be changed to the overwritten of string literal address by `unparse_symbol`.

Comment: what if i free it just before `return` statement ?

Comment: it can not execute. To be changed the `char *string = calloc(10, 1);` to `char *string;` (memory allocation is not required by `calloc`)

Comment: By passing the address of the string literal you will not be able to run `free`. (It has already rewritten.)

Comment: Yes you are right.. on `gcc` it is not running (`free`). But it is running on `dev-C++`. Can you please explain this a bit in more details.

Comment: `free` releases the memory allocated by `malloc` family. String literal is not possible to apply the `free` Because it not secured by `malloc`. Behavior when you pass such a invalid address to `free` is undefined. It probably will  a crash or somewhere to unexpected changes.